# Create column based on date conditions, but I get this error AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'sub'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hey a python newbie here.

Suppose I have the first two columns of this data dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ["Sun", "Moon", "Sun", "Moon", "Mars", "Mars"],
                   'score': [2, 13, 24, 15, 11, 44], 
                   'datetime': ["2017-08-30 07:00:00", "2017-08-30 08:00:00", "2017-08-31 07:00:00", "2017-08-31 08:00:00", "2017-08-29 21:00:00", "2017-08-28 21:00:00"],
                   'difference': [2, 13, 22, 2, -33, 44]})
```

I want to create a new column named `difference` (I have put it there as an illustration), such that
it is equal:

- score value in that row - score value of the day before in the same hour, for that group

e.g. difference in row 3 is equal to:
score in that row - score on the day before (30th) at `08:00:00` for that group (i.e. Moon), i.e. `15 - 13 = 2`. If the day before and same time do not exist, then the value of the score of that row is taken (e.g. in row 0, for time `2017-08-30 07:00:00` there is no `2017-08-29 07:00:00`, hence only the 2 is taken).

I write the following:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
before = df['datetime'] - pd.DateOffset(days=1)

df['difference'] = df.groupby(["group", "datetime"])['score'].sub(
    before.map(df.set_index('datetime')['score']), fill_value=0)
```

but I get the error:
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'sub'

What am I missing? IS there any more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `MultiIndex.map`

We can set the `group` column along with the `before` column as the index of the dataframe, then `map` the multiindex with score values belonging to the same `group` then subtract the mapped score values from the `score` column to calculate the difference.

```
s = df.set_index(['group', before]).index.map(df.set_index(['group', 'datetime'])['score'])
df['difference'] = df['score'].sub(list(s), fill_value=0)
```

---

```
>>> df

  group  score            datetime  difference
0   Sun      2 2017-08-30 07:00:00         2.0
1  Moon     13 2017-08-30 08:00:00        13.0
2   Sun     24 2017-08-31 07:00:00        22.0
3  Moon     15 2017-08-31 08:00:00         2.0
4  Mars     11 2017-08-29 21:00:00       -33.0
5  Mars     44 2017-08-28 21:00:00        44.0
```